# Eclipse RCP Plugin: Internationalization for non-Latin characters

Tags: internationalization, eclipse-rcp, non-latin

Im having trouble with Internationalizing my Eclipse RCP application for non-Latin characters.

I am storing Chinese characters in UTF-8 format in the property files. But reading them out does not work properly, they are all displayed like gibberish.

I am wondering if there is an easier way to do this, without overriding the provided NLS classes.

Answer (score 0):

Properties files are normally encoded as ISO-8859-1 and it is not a good idea to override this. You can specify Unicode characters in the file using \uNNNN notation.